# How to get names of files spooled for printing?

Tags: unix, printing, filenames, print-spooler

I need to get names of all files spooled for printing. How can I do this in Unix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lpstat` command can be used to list the print jobs queued for printing. To see all of them:

```
 lpstat -a
```

Comment: Thanks! That was obvious but i didnt get it..